# How do I check for required scopes in a discord bot user using Python?

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord API wrapper and I finally thought of embarking on commands. As most of you know, discord requires bots to have the `application.commands` scope for checking whether the bot user has permissions to receive application commands.

I wanted to check if the bot had the setting enabled using Python, but it never seems to work. I have tried many things and even have sifted through the documentation, but I am not able to find a solution. Can anyone help?

**My Attempts:**

- Tried to listen for any codes saying that the scope is not enabled
- Checked the docs for any status codes and handling scopes

Please help!

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#authorizing-your-application

Comment: Oh, and sorry, I cannot post the image because stack overflow isn't allowing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a workaround, but you could try to make a `get` request to the commands endpoint

```
GET /applications/{application.id}/guilds/{guild.id}/commands
```

If you get a `403 - Forbidden` then the bot doesn't have the `application.commands` scope

Comment: Yeah, I checked and turns out this is the only method. Anyways, thanks!